# Python function which takes two arrays of integers and returns the number of integers that occur in both arrays

Tags: python, arrays

For example, if it takes the arrays [1,44,5,8,35] and [35,12,44,7,42,31] it will return 2,
because exactly two integers (44 and 35) occur in both the arrays.
The code should be library free

I have tried the following code:

```
A = [1,44,5,8,35] 
B = [35,12,44,7,42,31]


def occurInBoth(A, B):
        for i in range(len(A)):
            for j in range(len(B)):
              if A[i] == B[j]:
                  newA = [A[i]]
                  print(newA)
                
occurInBoth(A, B)
```

The result I get is:
[44]
[35]

And I'd like to get 2 as a result

Just editing this question because due to the nature of this module I cannot use libraries, import anything, use intersection etc. I have researched how to do this but I can only get answers that I cannot use for this task. Sorry if this has been asked before but haven't found anything for this specific task

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with your for loops. What you want to do is create an accumulator value, and add 1 to it every time you find a match:

```
def occurInBoth(A, B):
    total = 0
    
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B)):
          if A[i] == B[j]:
              total += 1

    return total
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked! I thought somehow I had to put the common values in an array and then find the length of that array but this is much quicker

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is:

```
def function_array_intersect(arr1,arr2):
    return list(set(arr1).intersection(set(arr2)))


>>> function_array_intersect([1,2,3],[3,4,5])
Ans: [3]
```

Edit: to get the len, just add a `len(list(set(arr1).intersection(set(arr2))))` in the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If both lists only contain unique numbers (no duplicates within their own lists), the below code is the simplest solution. We just need to compare the length of A+B combined lists with the length of the same integers put into a set (which removes all duplicates).

```
def occurInBoth(a, b):
    return len(a+b) - len(set(a+b))
```